# How to remove certain set of line numbers in a text file using Python?

Tags: python, text

I need to delete for instance the following line numbers for instance;
line_numbers = [67,68,69]
How is it possible to do so? Actually, I am using the following code but it is not working.

```
f_in = 'Tendons_+Diagonals_Analysis1.tb'
f_out = 'Sample.tb'
_fileOne = open(f_in,'r')
f = open(f_out,'w')
    
counter=0
    
for line in fileinput.input([f_in]):
    counter = counter+1    
    if counter != (i for i in [67,68,69]):
          f.write(line)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
for line in _fileOne:
    counter = counter+1    
    if counter not in [67,68,69]:
        f.write(line)
     
f.close()
```

Calling `if counter != (i for i in [67,68,69])` is asking if `counter`, an `int`, is a generator expression `(i for i in [67,68,69])`, which it is not.

Also, as you already know, you're looking to remove a `set` of lines, not a `list` of lines, so it is more efficient to test

```
if counter not in {67, 68, 69}:
```

as opposed to

```
if counter not in [67, 68, 69]:
```

or

```
if counter not in (67, 68, 69):
```